# Read data stored in object and present in an expandable list view

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

in my Android app I've parsed data from an XML file and I put them in some object, now I've to read this data and present them in a expandable list view. I know how to display data in a expandable list view: I need an adapter, but to use the adapter I need first the data I stored in my object, so how I can read data from my objects?

EDIT: here you can see how should be my adapter.

**Myadapter.java**

```
package it.lucgian84.adapter;

import it.lucgian84.models.Episode;
import it.lucgian84.models.Program;
import it.lucgian84.models.Programs;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;

public class Myadapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Program> programList;

    public Myadapter(Context context, ArrayList<Program> programList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.programList = programList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Episode[] episodeList = programList.get(groupPosition).getEpisodes();
        return episodeList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, 
               View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int arg0, boolean arg1, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

So in the Activity I should populate the ArrayList programList to use in my adapter. To populate programList I need to read informations from my object, how I can populate programList?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some possible alternitaves for doing that. 
You could create a static class which holds the data in a staic field. Then you can access this object in your adapter through this static class.
You could also define a parameter for this type of object in your adapter class. So if you create a instance of your adapter you can instanciate it with the specific object.

Now you can access your objects in your adapter and use their information in your list view

Pseudo code:

```
public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter(){
   public MyAdapter(Object myObject){
        this.object = myObject;
   }
   //handleMethods
}
```

Hopes it helps

Cheers

Comment: I'm not realy sure what you do mean with populate. Do you want to put data into your ArrayList<Program> or what do you mean?

Comment: Then you have to create a method which returns the list in the adapter first. In the activity class which uses the adapter instanciates it and set the handler of the view. Then you can update the data of the list in your handler. And this handler will return the new list to the activity as the activity calls Tue getList() method.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
class Myadapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


     private Context contProgram     
     private ArrayList<Program> programList;

        public Myadapter(Context context, ArrayList<Program> programList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.programList = programList;
        }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2, View arg3, ViewGroup arg4) {

        Episode program = programList.get(arg0).getEpisodes().get(arg1);
         //your child view inflate from xml or add programatically
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
        return programList.get(arg0).getEpisodes().lenth;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
        return programList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int arg0, boolean arg1, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3) {
        Program program =  programList.get(arg0);
        //your group view inflate from xml or add programatically
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok this help me with adapter, but my issue comes before... I need to read the information from object and insert in the programList. I will do that in an activity, indeed, you can see that in my adapter I've a constructor. Can you help me to read information from the object and insert in the programList? Thank you